# error: expected unqualified-id before 'void'

Tags: c++, debugging, error-handling, compiler-errors

I have just started learning c++. I am trying to play with classes and objects in this code. The code is simply about taking the data contents of an array from the user and then as an output show the data contents of the array back.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class array
{
    public:
    int ar[5];

    void putData();
    void disp();
}


array :: void putData()
{
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cin>>ar[i];
    }
}

array :: void disp()
{
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout<<ar[i];<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    array m;
    m.putData();
    m.disp();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are getting error at which line?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan: Read the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array :: void putData()
```

Whoops...

It's supposed to be:

```
void array :: putData()
```

Or, rendered more clearly:

```
void array::putData()
```

It's because the full name of the function you're defining is `array::putData`; you accidentally butchered your return type (`void`) by writing the `array::` part in the wrong place.

Comment: `cout<<ar[i];<<endl;` could be a problem too

Comment: @Ilya: Yes but the OP didn't ask about that ;) And this isn't a code fixing service.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah... that was the error... Thank you very much... But that was a very silly syntax error :(

Comment: @MeetMangukiya: Indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define functions this way

```
void array::putData()
{
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cin>>ar[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this add to my answer?